# Iterative loop to remove specific unwanted characters from a string

Tags: python, for-loop, typeerror

I want to take the string 'APPLES_10_4' inside a dataframe and have it become 'APPLES'. The code I have come up with is below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['APPLES_10_4']

Name_Parameters = []
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit'], index = ['count'])

    
def badletters(lastletter):
    badletters = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","_"]
    if lastletter in badletters:
        return True
    else:
        return False   

def stripe(variable):
    tempStrippedVariable = variable
    foundEndVariable = False
    while not foundEndVariable:
        lastletter = tempStrippedVariable [:-1]
        if badletters(lastletter):
            tempStrippedVariable = tempStrippedVariable [:-1]
        else:
            foundEndVariable = True
    strippedVariable = tempStrippedVariable
    return strippedVariable

for variable in df:
strippedVariable = stripe(str(variable))
prefixes = []
if strippedVariable not in prefixes:
    prefixes.append(strippedVariable)
print(df)
```

The output I am getting is the original dataframe with ['APPLES_10_4'] not the altered one that says ['APPLES'].

Comment: Why not use `re.sub()`?

Comment: What does `prefixes` consist of?

Comment: prefixes would be the whole dataframe full of other strings like 'mangoes_1_5' so the prefixes should be an array of fruit names without any of the "badletters"

Comment: The error is because the dataframe contains numbers, not just strings.

Comment: try just `for variable in df: print(variable)` and you'll see them.

Comment: So the problem is actually when you call the ```stripe``` function. ```for variable in df``` sets ```variable``` to an integer and not the test data that you are giving.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dataframe elements are integers, not strings. You can convert them to strings before calling `stripe()`

```
for variable in df:
    strippedVariable = stripe(str(variable))
    if strippedVariable not in prefixes:
        prefixes.append(strippedVariable)
print(prefixes)
```

Or you could just skip them.

```
for variable in df:
    if not isinstance(variable, str):
        continue
    strippedVariable = stripe(variable)
    if strippedVariable not in prefixes:
        prefixes.append(strippedVariable)
print(prefixes)
```

Another bug is in `stripe()`:

```
lastletter = tempStrippedVariable [:-1]
```

should be

```
lastletter = tempStrippedVariable [-1]
```

You're setting `lastletter` to the entire string *except* the last letter.

But that whole function can be replaced with simply:

```
def stripe(variable):
    badletters = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","_"]
    return variable.rstrip(badletters)
```

Finally, `for variable in df` doesn't iterate over the dataframe contents, just the column names.  See [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas)

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    variable = row[0]
    strippedVariable = stripe(variable)
    if strippedVariable not in prefixes:
        prefixes.append(strippedVariable)
```

Comment: I changed my code to what you did above but the output I get is the dataframe column name ['fruits'] not the changed string 'APPLES'.

Comment: What do you see if you just do `print(variable)`?

Comment: print(variable) outputs fruit

Comment: The problem is the `for` loop, it's just iterating over the column names, not the data.

Comment: I changed the column name to "fruit_10_4" to see if it was at least stripping away the 'badletters' but it isn't. So does that mean my stripe function doesn't work either. Along with my problem of iterating the column names

Comment: Yeah, just try `print(stripe("fruit_10_4"))` and you'll see it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just `return variable.rstrip(badletters)`?

Comment: Where would I add that? and yeah my stripe variable doesn't work. Not sure where i went wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed all my problems.